# capturing Linq to object queries

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, linq-to-objects

Because of performance issue in application we are using in-memory approach for one of my project, in which we are loading all tables in RAM in form of generic collections (using nhibernate).

Issue is that when we were using simple linq to sql approach that time the testing and QA team were easily able to get sql queries using sql profiles for page they were viewing.

but with new approach (in-memory), we are loading all data in collection in one go and then are using linq to get data from that collection, so the testing and QA teams are not able to get the sql queries to verify the business logic and verifying bugs.

Please suggest any solution which can help in this situation, i think its not possible to get sql from linq to object (as all data is already in collection). please suggest any solution/approach/tool which can help me, to generate sql of those linq which is getting run against the collection or any other good solution.

NOTE: i know getting sql out of linq to sql is not possible, i am looking for suggestion which can help my QA and testing team to verify the queries/business logic (like they were doing earlier by capturing sql). like if possible log the linq queries as string which can be further used to be run/analyze.

Answer (score 2):

The only SQL statements that you are running in this situation are the initial SELECT queries to load your data into memory. Once you have done those, you are no longer running "queries", you are instead performing .NET Framework calls.

Given that you have fundamentally changed the architecture of the application, you need to communicate this to the testing and QA teams - they will not be able to "see" what the application is now doing under the hood in the way that they could previously. If this sort of "deep dive" capability is a requirement of your test teams then your architecture is likely to require further modifications.

Comment: can you please provide more detail on what further modification is required?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. However, the crucial thing to understand is that you're not now executing SQL statements against a database - you are calling .NET Framework methods on data that is in-memory.

Comment: I understand this thing that getting sql is not possible.. i am looking for any other mechanism, to either lets say write linq query as a string or any other kind of strategy..

Comment: As I said previously, it depends on your requirements. If you need to be able to show your QA and testing teams *exactly* what you are doing under the bonnet, then give them the source code. Otherwise you will need to write out (to file maybe) all of the LINQ expressions you are executing - however, this may not satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Even if i give source code, will have to teach them .net, linq and debugging process.. :)